# Format Contribution Form Using Pricesets

Tags: civicontribute, price-sets

We are creating a contribution page using a price set which is new to us. The format is a little weird. Is there a way to align the email address with the entries above it? Or can we eliminate the email address above the 'Donor Info' like and include it into the profile below? See image below.

Thanks in advance.

Using Civicrm 4.7.8 and Joomla 3.5.1

[image]
<sub>(source: [corvair.org](https://www.corvair.org/supportCorvairs.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CiviCRM uses page template files to render its pages. These can be customized. On the developer Wiki is described how this is done. See https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Page+Templates .

The template where you can change the offending email lay-out is
`[civicrm.root]/templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl`

Search for the following code:

```
{assign var=n value=email-$bltID}
<div class="crm-public-form-item crm-section {$form.$n.name}-section">
  <div class="label">{$form.$n.label}</div>
  <div class="content">
    {$form.$n.html}
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't recommend hacking the template. Use css for simple style tweaks.

Answer (score 3):

For a short-term solution, consider adding some css to your page that fixes the styling.

For the medium-term, check out issue [CRM-15067](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15067) which aims to solve this problem.

Comment: I used a custom template to add a line feed to before the email label. Changed <div class="label">{$form.$n.label}</div> to 
<br><div class="label">{$form.$n.label}</div>